# webkit box vs boxflex

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox

I recently ran across a tutorial where the instructor used this syntax:

```
display: -webkit-box;
```

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-MNkBh7F2A @ 2:30 (created aug 2012)

I hadn't seen this before and began trying to find some info on it.  It seems CSS3 has something called flexbox.  But I couldn't find references the above syntax.

In this article http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/, written a year before the above tutorial (sept 2011), they use this syntax:

```
display: box;
```

and mentioned box will be replaced with flexbox.

I'm still not sure what the benefit of flexbox or box is.  I don't see people using it.  Can someone give a basic summary of it?

Also, why does the tutorial use -webkit-box?  Is *box* webkit specific? Why didn't he use

display: box;

Does -webkit-box mean it only works in Safari and Chrome?

If it is cross browser compatible, which browsers and versions does it work with?

*box* (non webkit) seems to be cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this topic summarizes it the best: http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Basically Flexbox has 3 different "iterations" of the markup.  The old 2009 markup, the still old 2011 markup, and the "new" markup which isn't officially released or supported yet.It's important to note that despite the video you linked to being uploaded in 2012, the guy who made the video is using the really old 2009 implementation of flexbox.  I would suggest NOT following that tutorial.

Here are some more resources:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/

And Can I Use it?
http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Nice, thanks.  So I'd have to say a definite "no" to using flexbox. Only partial support for IE10, FF 19 - 21, and Safari 5.1 - 6.0.  Chrome has the best support.  There just aren't enough browsers using it.  Do you read it the same way?

Comment: Some people would not consider it a definite no, in-fact there are people using the new model now and there are ways to provide graceful degradation, but I consider it more work than it is worth at the present moment.  That said, I do believe there are some javascript "polyfills" out there for the new flexbox model but I don't off hand know of any.  Such an example is flexie.js - but that's for the "old" 2011 iteration of the specification.  All things considered, it's a magnificent bit of code and is extremely powerful, but for now I say be patient, and wait for official support

Comment: Opera and Chrome are both using the standard properties.

Answer (score -9):

the -webkit-box is the latest and saves so much time on using the old style which requires a lot of javascript ,so in designing with the webkit you are producing your work to the latest standards and a big saving on man hours.