# Display Properties are not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, properties, webkit, display

```
.action {
  display : -webkit-box;
  display : flex;
  margin-left : auto;
  color : transparent;
  -webkit-transition : .1s;
  transition : .1s;
}
```

The above Css code is working in IE. But In chrome display:-webkit-box and -webkit-transition:.1s are not working. the properties gets strike in chrome console. I want to show it too.

Comment: I think this solution can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654036/13337672

Comment: "the properties gets strike in chrome console" - Thats becasue Chrome uses the standards compliant properties: `display: flex` and `transition: .1s`. The -webkit- prefixes have not been required for years in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Those are struck through because duplicate properties take the value that is last in the list:

```css
div {
 color: red;
 color: blue;
 color: green;
}
```

The end result of the above will be `green`

At least it does so as long as it recognizes the value given as something understandable:

```css
div {
 font-weight: 400;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-weight: red;
}
```

Here font-weight will be 500, because 'red' is not a valid value.

Worth noing here is that `-webkit-transitions` and `transition` are considered the same property.